# Tests run fine one by one but fail a lot when run in parallel

Tags: multithreading, webdriver, selenium-grid, stalestateexception

I have the following problem:

I've created a bunch of test using WebDriver + Java + TestNG + Maven which work just fine when I run them one by one- when the thread-count is 1 in my testng.xml file but when I increase the number of threads the tests start failing, most common issues I am getting are:
1. stale element reference exceptions
2. timeouts
3. keyboard actions do not work in most cases

As for now I am running the tests either just through testng.xml or selenium grid (2.3.1 server) on my local machine using only firefox browser 23.0.1.

Any answer or ideas will be helpful, thanks!

Comment: Can you show how you are creating your webdriver object. Are you storing it in a static variable? Are you running parallel on classes or methods ? Are your instances opening on different machines?

Comment: @RobbieWareham,
Here are the answers to your questions:
1. Each test case extends TestTemplate class which has a class variable: protected ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> threadDriver = null. After I pass a parameter from testng.xml file for each test case, the browser is set through a utils method and the driver is initialized in BeforeClass method: threadDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + host + ":" + port + "/wd/hub"), capability)). After that I am using the driver instance in the test case.
2. I am running parallel on classes, and here is a piece of my testng.xml:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" preserve-order="true"
 thread-count="3" verbose="5">
 <test name="TestI">
  <parameters>
   <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
   <parameter name="port" value="4444" />
   <parameter name="host" value="localhost" />
      </parameters>
  <classes>
   <class name="TestName.class" />
  </classes>
 </test>
  ......here I have multiple tests.......
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Comment: 3. As for now I am doing the simplest thing: running the tests on localhost machine with only firefox browser.